# What does いちいちパスタ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 日本のスパゲッティは、**いちいちパスタ**と言っていて奇妙です。

I don't see what could mean "one by one pasta" in this context?

Comment: look up いちいち by itself. If you still have questions, let us know what was confusing about the vocabulary.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27359/5010

Comment: I looked in the dictionary before asking this question and I have now looked the question posted by Naruto but I still don't understand in this particular case what it means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As was mentioned in naruto's link, **いちいち** is a word that implies that someone is saying or doing something step by step or giving a long-winded explanation, and helps convey the speaker's annoyance about this.

いちいち言って　is basically "to annoyingly insist" or "to keep saying over and over (despite my lack of interest/despite how unimportant it is)" or "to go on and on about"

> 日本のスパゲッティは、いちいちパスタと言っていて奇妙です。

would thus be translated as something along the lines of

```
"It's strange to harp on and on, insisting on calling Japanese spaghetti a 'pasta' dish."
```

or adhering more closely to the Japanese word order:

```
"For Japanese spaghetti, annoyingly insisting on referring to it as 'pasta' is strange."
```